# Jest vue3: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' (signalr)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, jestjs, babeljs

I am trying to connect tests to my project but they are not working

What can you do about it?

ERROR:
Test suite failed to run
Details:

```
   E:\Work\repos\WebRep\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\index.js:3
   export { AbortError, HttpError, TimeoutError } from "./Errors";

   SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

   > 1 | import * as signalR from '@microsoft/signalr/dist/esm/index';
       |  ^
     2 | import EventEmitter from '../helpers/event-emitter';
     3 | import * as scheduleNamespace from '../interfaces/schedules/schedules-dto';
     4 | import * as projectNamespace from '../interfaces/projects/projects-dto';

     at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1597:14)
     at Object.<anonymous> (src/signalr-client/signalr.ts:1:2)
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5PQM.png)

jest.config.js

```
// jest.config.js
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest/utils');
// In the following statement, replace `./tsconfig` with the path to your `tsconfig` file
// which contains the path mapping (ie the `compilerOptions.paths` option):
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig');

module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'json', 'node'],
  transform: {
    '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue3-jest',
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.scss$': 'jest-scss-transform',
    '^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules'],
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$',
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, { prefix: '<rootDir>/' }),
  collectCoverage: true,
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
};
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, most third-party libs need to be mocked in tests. Use jest.mock.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks